# arraybuffor into audio src

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I'm getting a arraybuffer from http response. The code below plays the audio just once but I want to to use audio as src for audio element!

```js
    this.toSpeechService.getAudioFile(this.text).subscribe(res => {
       const context = new AudioContext();
       let source = context.createBufferSource();
       context.decodeAudioData(res, function(buffer) {
            source.buffer = buffer;
          }, null).then(() => {
            source.connect(context.destination);
            this.audioSrc = context.destination; // doesn't fill the audio player
            source.start(0);
       });
       console.log(res)
     });
```

```html
    <audio controls="controls">
      <source [src]="audioSrc" type="audio/mp3/wav" />
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you know the mime type of the data in the `ArrayBuffer` the following should work.

```
this.toSpeechService.getAudioFile(this.text).subscribe(res => {
    const blob = new Blob([ res ], { type: THE_MIME_TYPE });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    YOUR_AUDIO_ELEMENT.src = url;
    YOUR_AUDIO_ELEMENT.load();
});
```

`THE_MIME_TYPE` is a placeholder for the actual mimeType. And `YOUR_AUDIO_ELEMENT` is a reference to your audio element.

Once you don't need the object URL anymore you can release the memory by calling `URL.revokeObjectURL(url)`.

Comment: This does create a url (https://localhost:4200/afad9eca-0385-4bab-9ac2-47aaced43b2b) but  my audio element is still empty and plays nothing!

Comment: The URL looks as expected. What does "empty" mean in this case? Does it allow you to click the play button? Did you set the mimeType?

Comment: Actually your code just needs a YOUR_AUDIO_ELEMENT.load(); at the end and audio element plays the audio. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I updated the answer. I was under the impression that it should not be necessary.